# Change title look with CSS

Tags: html, css

I have an issue creating a title for a web page.
Here is title:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

.title {
  border-top: 2px solid grey;
  color: grey;
  text-size:20px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="title">Düsseldorf markets</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I need to move the market word to the bottom and it should be displayed like that:

```
Düsseldorf 
markets
```

Any idea how can I do it with the help of CSS only(i.e how can I change title CSS class to get desired view)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use padding-right with calculation. `padding-right: calc(100% - 10ch);` This is very simple, no complex.

```css
.title {
  border-top: 2px solid grey;
  color: grey;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-right: calc(100% - 10ch); /* Düsseldorf is 10 character */
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="title">Düsseldorf markets</div>
```

Comment: thanks nice! What if I want to add padding row to the title class:padding: 10px 0px 0px 0px; so I guess padding-right will not work

Comment: `padding: 10px calc(100% - 10ch) 0px 0px;`

Comment: Thanks! Seems that it's new feature

Comment: 10 characters doesn't mean 10ch. It's only valid for monospace fonts where all the character have the same width equal to the one of 0 that is defining the ch unit

Comment: @TemaniAfif oh thanks. I have never ever heard that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a CSS hack to acheive this if you really want to use CSS only. First, make the text disappear by setting it to the color of the background. Then use the `before` and `after` selectors to rerender the content.

However, easier would be to use `span` tags in your HTML, then make each of them have `display: block` to get a line break.

Example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

:root {
  --font_size: 20px;
  --text_col: grey;
  --text_margin: 10px;
}

.title {
  border-top: 2px solid grey;
  font-size: var(--font_size);
  color: white;
}

.title:before {
   content: "Düsseldorf";
   color: var(--text_col);
   position: absolute;
   left: 10px;
   top: var(--text_margin);
}

.title:after {
   content: "markets";
   color: var(--text_col);
   position: absolute;
   left: 10px;
   top: calc(var(--font_size) + var(--text_margin));
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="title">Düsseldorf markets</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for post, But I need the border with the same width

Comment: @Michael Why not create two separate `p` tags in your `div` with each word then?

Comment: Because I get it as single line

Comment: @Michael Edited to keep border. But this is more of a hack than a proper solution. Best would be to use `span` or `p` tags in your `div`. This shouldn't have any noticable impact on SEO since web crawlers have gotten smart these days

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to approach this - use a `width` property on a element. Then, by `word-break` rule (which is 'normal' by default and you don't need to specify this) words will be auto-wrap on next line, when there is no free place on container

[here is demo](https://codepen.io/immdevrov/pen/vYLZKyp)

P.S. And you have a typo - did you mean `font-size` except for `text-size`?